# Launch4j не подгружает jar и dependecies

Tags: java, maven, jar, exe

Всем привет, создала exe файл с помощью `launch4j`, все нормально, проект запускается, но есть некоторые части которые не работают без `jar` и `dependencies`, описанных в `pom.xml` проекта. `Launch4j` просто не подгрузил их. Можно ли как-то ему сказать, чтоб он это сделал, или есть другие варианты как из `jar` создать исполняемый `exe` файл? Заранее всем спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вашу проблему решит `maven-assembly-plugin`. Этот плагин компилирует Ваш исходный код и все зависимости проекта в один `*.jar` файл.

Добавьте этот плагин в `pom.xml` в раздел `<plugins>`:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

После компиляции Вашего проекта воспользуйтесь `launch4j` и сделайте из получившегося `<ИМЯ_БИБЛИОТЕКИ>-jar-with-dependencies.jar` файла исполняемый файл `*.exe`.